# Проблема с установкой npm с прокси

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

Установил NodeJs. Система windows 7 x64. В компании установлен прокси, поэтому файл C:\Users\User\ .npmrc выглядит примерно таким образом:

```
http-proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080
https-proxy=https://user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
```

Для установки последней версии npm, мне требуется ввести команду npm install npm@latest в папке с nodejs. Запускаю от админа. Но при этому командная строка выдает:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install npm@latest
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!    C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-19T02_39_10_611Z-debug.log
```

На домашнем компьютере без прокси все установилось.С прокси же не хочет никак.

Вот лог:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'npm@latest' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v9.11.1
4 verbose npm-session 88190ff7075774fc
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for npm@latest request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:
8 verbose type system
9 verbose stack FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:
9 verbose stack
9 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
9 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:180:13)
9 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:395:9)
9 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:180:13)
9 verbose stack     at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
9 verbose stack     at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:453:5)
9 verbose stack     at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:39:7)
9 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.Socket._destroy (net.js:548:3)
9 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:32:8)
9 verbose stack     at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:846:10)
10 verbose cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
11 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
12 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm@latest"
13 verbose node v9.11.1
14 verbose npm  v5.6.0
15 error code EPROTO
16 error errno EPROTO
17 error request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

UPD:

Нашел странное решение, которое помогло продвинуться чуть дальше. Настройки прокси должны быть заданы таким образом:

```
http-proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080
https-proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080
```

То есть https-proxy и https-proxy - одинаковы.

Установка npm началась, но в конце концов снова появились ошибки:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install npm@latest
npm WARN rollback Rolling back npm@5.8.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\html\doc\cli'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\package.json'
npm WARN nodejs No description
npm WARN nodejs No repository field.
npm WARN nodejs No README data
npm WARN nodejs No license field.

npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm.DELETE'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm.DELETE'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm.DELETE'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!      path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm',
npm ERR!      dest: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.npm.DELETE' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename \'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\' -> \'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.npm.DELETE\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.npm.DELETE' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-19T03_24_18_952Z-debug.log
```

Лог очень длинный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема действительно решилась установкой прокси таким образом.

```
http-proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080
https-proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.company.com:8080
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
```

Просто нужно было переустановить nodejs.